# Where is certificate specified for aws host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

My certificate has expired and I recreated and reassociated with a load balancer.

The certificate has `*.example.com` and `example.com` attached (?) to it

and I can see that certificate works by visiting `https://example.com`.

Then I try to visit `https://log.example.com` and it errors with `NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID` (It must be the old expired certificate which is causing the error)

Question is, how can I let the new certificate to be used for the ec2 machine?

EDIT

`log.example.com` is not behind loadbalancer, it's directly mapped via IP address

Comment: Can you confirm that all the domains are behind the sae load balancer?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams log.littlehome.kr is not behind load balancer it's connected through ip

Comment: Is the SSL certificate via ACM or purchased seperately?

Comment: it's ACM (created from aws console)

Comment: That certificate cannot be applied directly to the host, an ACM certificate can only be bound to either CloudFront or a load balancer. You will either need to apply one of these in front of your server or make use of something like certbot or a paid CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate being served by `log.example.com` is not using the ACM certificate attached to load balancer for `example.com` as it is served directly by the IP address.

You are limited to the following options:

- If you want to use an ACM certificate you will need to either add a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) or a load balancer in front of your application. The DNS record for `log.example.com` would need to be changed to the new resource.
- If you want to use direct connection to your instance then you are limited to using another certificate authority. You can use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to generate a free certificate, or purchase one from another provider. This will then need to be installed and configured on your server to use.